# Condense async actions with AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I'm trying to update DynamoDB in a particular way when a Lambda function is called. At the moment, every time the lambda function is called, I have to actually wait for the update to occur. This takes a full second each time. Is there a way that I can "fire and forget" or just not have the full back-and-forth time billed? Almost all of the time the lambda expression is evaluating occurs during this asynchronous time. I expect it to be called a dozen times a second or so, so reducing it by like 90% would be awesome.

Thanks!

P.S. I'm writing in JavaScript, but I'd be willing to switch to another language to do this (I'm familiar with all of them, and it's a function that's under 100 lines)

Comment: What language is your Lambda function written in?

Comment: JavaScript -- sorry, will update the question.

Comment: Would be willing to switch if it changed the circumstance for the better.

Answer (score 0):

When you say wait for the update do you mean that you are doing a `putItem` and then polling with `getItem` until the value you expect is returned?

That's generally an anti-pattern so I'm curious if you could add more about your use case. Generally you would use a conditional write/read so that you don't need to poll.

Something like:

```
Client == Client that needs new record updated
Client - update -> Lambda - (Update with Version/timestamp) -> DDB - 200 ->  Lambda - Saved Version/Timestamp -> Client - (Get/Update with Version/Timestamp) -> DDB
```

As long as you want to poll for verification (which uses CPU time) you will be paying for it in Lambda. Fear not however, there are a few options available to you (again depending on what it is you're actually trying to accomplish).

1. Push your polling into your frontend client
2. Use DDB streams to notify your client etc...